# Child Form Object References Returning Incorrect Values

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, parent-child

**Problem**

So I have a parent form that uses a child form to contain various settings to be used.  The settings form has things such as datagridviews, textboxes, listviews, etc.  The parent form is called "MainForm" and the settings one is called "SQL_Settings".  Whenever referencing items from the child form within the parent form I get incorrect results.

For example:

```
Sql_settings.Datagridview.rows.count
```

Returns a value of 1 but I can physically see there are definitely more than one rows in it.

Another example:

```
Sql_settings.Textbox1.text
```

Returns blank even though there is text in it.

**Possible reason?**

I started having this problem after experimenting with multi-threading and delegates.  I had at one point used the command:

```
 System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

but then deleted it deciding to do it correctly instead.  I am thinking maybe something is "left over" from this command?  I could be entirely wrong on that though..

**Additional Information**

```
    Dim data_to_pass(2) As Object
    data_to_pass(0) = SQL_Settings.DataGridView1(3, sql_on).Value
    data_to_pass(1) = part_information
    data_to_pass(2) = ListView8

    Dim add_results_thread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf add_results_to_list)

    add_results_thread.IsBackground = True
    add_results_thread.Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest
    add_results_thread.Start(data_to_pass)
```

This does run multiple times however. Once the thread is done then it is triggered to run another one after. Perhaps this is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Basically since my thread creation is happening within a loop I have to ensure that the previous thread is completed before executing the next one. To do this I added a delegate that is fired at the end of the thread which then allows me to then access the UI thread again. This solution works for me so hopefully it helps those in the future too.

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms all code that accesses UI elements (including DataGridView and TextBox controls) must run on the same thread (the UI thread). Your main form code definitely runs on the UI thread, and when you access `Sql_settings.Textbox1.text` from the main form you are definitely accessing code on the UI thread as well.

This means that the reason you are getting *invalid data* is likely not related to cross-thread issues. But it could be related to your objects life-cycle. Perhaps you are creating multiple instances of the SQL settings form and accessing one of the instances that doesn't have the data you are expecting.

Comment: I definitely agree with you about them being on separate threads.  I don't believe I am creating multiple instances though. I will post above the code I use for starting the new thread. Perhaps a solution could be to pass the parameters required by my thread upon creation of it?

Comment: If you put a break-point on this line: `add_results_thread.Start(data_to_pass)` and inspect the values in the array, what do you get? If the values are incorrect there then the issue has nothing to do with the threads.

Comment: The values are as they should be. I am trying to investigate the threading

Comment: If the values are what you expect, every time that line is reached than the problem is most likely in how you un-pack that data on your background thread. Maybe you should post that as well, and more specifically the code where the values are not what you'd expect..

Comment: Public Sub add_results_to_list(ByVal data_to_pass() As Object)


        Dim result_names As String = data_to_pass(0)
        Dim part_info_listview As ListView = data_to_pass(1)
        Dim data_listview As ListView = data_to_pass(2)

Comment: Eric, access to the `part_info_listview` and `data_listview` will have to be invoked on the UI thread in your `add_results_to_list` method. But it still doesn't explain why you would be getting corrupted data.

Comment: Check out my solution.  it was mostly because of the looping factor. Thank you very much for your help.